# flex: compile swf with maven

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flash, swc

I have several maven modules (each with a pom)
I am looking to compile my swf without first compiling each module into a swc, like i am soing now.
I suppose that should speed up the compilation process.

How should I do it, and is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to compile your SWC modules because they didn't change since the last compilation.
If that's the case (and if you use Flexmojos 4.x), please have a look at the [quick compile mode](https://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/maven-sites/flexmojos/4.1-beta/compile-swc-mojo.html#quick)

> Quick compile mode. When true, Flexmojos will check if the latest artifact available at maven repository for this project is newer then sources. If so, wont recompile.